# C getting number of lines in a text file of words

Tags: c, pointers, random, character, line

So I'm trying to get the number of lines in a text file of words each on a new line. I have this method so far...

```
char * getS(char *fileName){
    FILE *src;
    if((src = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("%s %s %s", "Cannot open file ", fileName, ". The program is now ending.");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char *get = ".";        

    int c = 0;
    char ch = 'x';
    while(ch!=EOF) {
        ch = fgetc(src);
        if(ch == '\n')  c++;
    }
    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("%i",c);
    int random = rand() % (c - 1);
    return get;
}
```

For some reason if I put a printf for ch in the middle of the while it will give me the correct number of lines, otherwise it 7801729.

Also how would I make a random int from 0 to the number of lines? The concept of using random in C is rather baffling to me right now.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you mean to put a newline after the value for `c`?  *ie* `printf("%i\n", c);`

Comment: P.S. Don't forget to `fclose(src)`!  And it's probably not a good idea to return a locally-scoped pointer to a temporary value.

Comment: Okay, and do any of those values correspond to the correct number of lines in your file? (possibly off-by-one)

Comment: Ah yes 78, it's actually 79 but whatever

Comment: Why does it give me all those other gibberish numbers?

Comment: It's off-by one because if the file doesn't end in a newline character, you don't currently consider the last line as being valid.  Only you can answer your other question.  It's most likely you are calling the function three extra times with other filenames.

Comment: Ah yes it is you genius. Yes it is...

Comment: As far as the random part of your question, make sure to initialize the random number generator with something like: srand(time(NULL));

Comment: yes I did that exactly, but how would I get a random number from the 1st line to the last?

Comment: You're already doing that.  But maybe just use `c` instead of `c-1`.  Using modulo (the `%` operator) will return a number between zero and one less than whatever number you give.

Comment: @OstapHnatyuk, just to add a small detail, you could rather use a `do/while` construct than initializing `ch` with a random value. Also, using `fgets()` would make your program much faster as it reads only till the next newline. Here, you are basically running a loop for each character in your file, which is pretty expensive!

Comment: It uses less ram though, so you could even run this on your toaster. Haha, yeah I understand I should have used fgets(). I was just very lazy, and I just used recycled code.

Answer (score 2):

I think fgetc() returns an int but you are stuffing the returned value into a char (without casting it to a char) so you're getting the first byte of the returned int in the right place (in your ch variable) but the additional three bytes overflow into your c variable, which is defined adjacent to ch on the stack. When you increment c, it's increasing the first byte (which suggests you're on a big-endian machine) but those extra three bytes in your int are untouched and left corrupted by the overwrite from the getc() return. That's why the first byte in your answer looks correct. Try defining ch as an int and I bet your problem goes away (though you might have to add some casting to avoid compiler errors/warnings).